# Create pagination that not destroy first query

Tags: php, mysql, pagination

I made a webpage that brings images on right side and I created a clickable link on image for view or display on the left side. **It works**. But after I  created a pagination of that list when I click on next page it distroys first query of displayed image on left side and creates error. How to hold that query?

Comment: There isn't nearly enough information in this question to even begin imagining what might be the issue in your code. It's a vague description of a vague problem. Please share your code and explain where the problem is in the code by editing the question. Code can be indented with a tab or four spaces to be formatted as code here on SO.

Comment: I am reluctant to put this as an answer as the question is vague but I felt like I'd try. [answer](https://pastebin.com/wzYaCxbt)